# Devise Routing Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Currently, devise has the URLs as `/users/sign_in` although I'd like to change this to `/signin`.

In the `routes.rb` file, I've tried this:

```
devise_for :users do
    get "/signin" => "devise/sessions#new"
    match '/signin', :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
    get "/signout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    match '/signout', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy'   
end
```

But nothing has worked. I get an error saying:

```
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:19:in `show'
```

In the `show` section, I have

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @post }
  end
end
```

What does `show` in the controller have to do with devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
 devise_scope :user do
   get   "/signin"  => "devise/sessions#new"
   match '/signin'  => 'devise/sessions#new'
   get   "/signout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
   match '/signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' 
 end
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Comment: I'm getting this error; `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:19:in 'show'`

Comment: Can you tell us which is the 19 line and also give us your app/models/post.rb ?

Comment: Line 19 is the second line in the `show` section which is included in the question. In the post.rb I have: class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name

  belongs_to :user
end